# addCookie in WebResponse duplicates Cookie-Header

Tags: wicket

in my wicket-project i have to add a cookie to the response. So i generate a new cookie an add it to the WebResponse.

```
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle;
import org.apache.wicket.request.http.WebResponse;

...
WebResponse webResponse = (WebResponse) RequestCycle.get().getResponse();
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("foo", "bar");
webResponse.addCookie(cookie);
...
```

This works as it should, except for the fact that the cookie-header is set twice.

```
curl -I <myHost>/<myApplication>/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: foo=bar
Set-Cookie: foo=bar
Date: Tue, 21 Jul 2015 13:54:29 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

I found no bug in jira of the wicket-project, but could it be one? Or am i doing it wrong?

Comment: what method contains the cookie adding code?

Comment: I registered my specific RequestCycleListener, in **onBeginRequest** of this listener i check the request for my cookie and add a new one if it's not present.

Answer (score 1):

`webResponse.addCookie()` just adds the Cookie object to an `ArrayList`, so if it's already in the list, adding it again will add a second instance in the list. You must have placed your Cookie adding code in a method that gets called twice. That's why you're getting two of them.

You can't even check that the Cookie is already added, because WebResponse provides no `getCookie()` method.

What you could do is clear the Cookie before adding it:

```
WebResponse webResponse = (WebResponse) RequestCycle.get().getResponse();

Cookie cookie = new Cookie("foo", "bar");
webResponse.clearCookie(cookie);
webResponse.addCookie(cookie);
```

If this doesn't work, an alternative solution would be to use a flag to indicate if the Cookie has already been added:

```
private boolean cookieAdded;

...

WebResponse webResponse = (WebResponse) RequestCycle.get().getResponse();

if (!cookieAdded) {
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("foo", "bar");
    webResponse.addCookie(cookie);
    cookieAdded = true;
}
```

Comment: This was the first thing i have checked. I'm searching the cookies from the request and add a new one, if my cookie was not sent. I placed this check and add the cookie in onBeginRequest of my own RequestCycleListener. This method is only called once per request.

Comment: Interesting. Can you set a breakpoint in BufferedHttpServletResponse.addCookie() to establish how many times it's called?